# using json files for properties with apache commons configuration2

Tags: java, json, apache-commons-configuration

I am trying to enable usage of JSON for configuration properties.
Upgraded to Commons Configuration2 (2.8) hoping that this will work out-of-the box.
I am initializing like this:

```java
new CombinedConfigurationBuilder()
            .configure(new Parameters()
                .fileBased()
                .setFileName(CONFIGURATION_SOURCES)
                .setEncoding(UTF_8.toString()))
            .getConfiguration();
```

This is my `CONFIGURATION_SOURCES` file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <properties fileName="this-works.properties" />
  <properties fileName="this-does-not-work.json" />
</configuration>
```

My JSON properties file (which does not get loaded):

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

When testing it with

```java
    @Test
    public void shouldLoadPropertiesFromJson() {
        assertThat(configuration.getString("foo"), is("bar"));
    }
```

fails because `foo` is `null` instead of `bar` :(

Any suggestion(s)?

Comment: If you want to have a single `CombinedConfiguration` using a standard properties file and also a JSON file, then I don't think that is supported. You _can_ do this with an XML file, using `<xml fileName="whatever.xml"/>` - see the examples [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_combinedbuilder.html). But there is nothing like `<json fileName=.../>`. Maybe there is another way - if so that would get my vote.

Comment: Yes, I want to have a single CombinedConfiguration referencing multiple property files with different formats.